# .htaccess removes query parameters

Tags: .htaccess, flask, mod-rewrite, cgi

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/app.cgi/$1 [QSA]
```

It works and my CGI app receives requests. But the problem is that it isn't getting query parameters. For example: if I request `www.example.com/foo?bar=0` the CGI app only receives `www.example.com/foo`. The `?bar=0` is removed.

What I need is when I hit `www.example.com/foo?bar=0` in the browser, the app receives `www.example.com/foo?bar=0`, not `www.example.com/foo`.

My server setup:

- nginx
- python
- flask
- mysql

File structure:

- `www/`

  - `project/`

    - `app.cgi`
    - other files
  - `.htaccess`

I'm new to writing such configs, so I don't know what should I do.

Comment: Rule which you have written will rewrite url from `www.example.com/foo` TO `www.example.com/foo?bar=0` in browser. Are you hitting `www.example.com/foo?bar=0` in browser and need `www.example.com/foo`? Could you please confirm once on same.

Comment: I hit `www.example.com/foo?bar=0` in browser and need `www.example.com/foo?bar=0` in my app

Comment: Ok, one more question here, in your rule file you have entry like  `/path/to/app.cgi` so do you mean here that you want to pass query string(things after `?` from URL) to another file? Why because from `www.example.com/foo?bar=0` url TO redirect url `www.example.com/foo?bar=0` are looking same, could you please clarify on same once.

Comment: Things after `?` sign have to go to the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, query parameters were already passed. I discovered it by using `.php` files. But my code still wasn't able to get query string.

The reason was that when Flask app is running as CGI app, query parameters are passed as environment variable. So in order to get them I had to use `os.environ.get('QUERY_STRING')`.